# ArgumentException when adding rows from DataGridView to DataTable

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

I'm fairly new to C# programming. I want to take user input from DataGridView to a DataTable. However, I get ArgumentException from this code

```
DataTable dd=new DataTable();
       foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dataGridView1.Rows)
       {
           dd.Rows.Add(dr);
       }
```

Is there any way I can do to fix it? I'd like to have alternatives to get input from `dataGridView1` as well.
edit: forgot to mention, `dataGridView1` has one comboBox column.
edit2: the error read "Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table.

You have to add a column to `DataTable` eg: `dd.Columns.Add("SomeColumnName")`, before you add rows to it.

However, if there's no particular requirement to use `DataTable` then you should use, for example, [`List`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) to store the rows. It is a much simpler data structure.

```
var listOfRows = gridView.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().ToList();
```

Comment: ah, I forgot to mention that i will manipulate the data to show it again in another form, so I think I need DataTable. But thanks for pointing out my mistake!